# How to avoid SAXParseException; The reference to entity "CONFORT" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: html, xml, parsing, saxparser

I'm having this SAXParseException when I try to parse an xml file.

Error trace:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:3107: The reference to entity "CONFORT" must end with the ';' delimiter.
Nuxeo-Importer-1 17:05:26,140 ERROR [EPJSourceNode] java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 3107; The reference to entity "CONFORT" must end with the ';' delimiter.
Nuxeo-Importer-1 17:05:26,146 ERROR [SolocalDocumentFactory] Erreur pendant l'import de EPJ code '52694992', cause : Impossible de creer l'etablissement, le nom est null 
Content
Dump size :0

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :97
Actual   :0
 <Click to see difference>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:542)
    at com.solocal.importer.test.TestImport.shouldImport(TestImport.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.test.runner.FeaturesRunner$15.evaluate(FeaturesRunner.java:472)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.test.runner.FeaturesRunner$BeforeMethodRunStatement.evaluate(FeaturesRunner.java:351)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.test.runner.FeaturesRunner$BeforeSetupStatement.evaluate(FeaturesRunner.java:367)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.test.runner.FeaturesRunner$AfterMethodRunStatement.evaluate(FeaturesRunner.java:398)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.test.runner.FeaturesRunner$AfterTeardownStatement.evaluate(FeaturesRunner.java:417)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.test.runner.FeaturesRunner$RulesFactory$1.evaluate(FeaturesRunner.java:530)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.test.runner.RuntimeDeployment$DeploymentStatement.evaluate(RuntimeDeployment.java:265)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.test.runner.RuntimeFeature$2$1.evaluate(RuntimeFeature.java:124)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.test.runner.FeaturesRunner$AfterClassStatement.evaluate(FeaturesRunner.java:290)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.test.runner.FeaturesRunner$RulesFactory$1.evaluate(FeaturesRunner.java:530)
    at org.nuxeo.runtime.test.runner.FeaturesRunner$BeforeClassStatement.evaluate(FeaturesRunner.java:273)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:130)
```

My error message brought up other posts about XML errors and escaping the & and the proposed solutions consist of using '&amp ;' instead of & but in my case, I'm using already &
I use a basic SAXParser with default configuration and a UTF-8 encoding.

The line bellow is throwing above exception.

```
<IN_RSE_LI_NOMEN>DESIGN &amp;CONFORT</IN_RSE_LI_NOMEN>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This should be valid. It seems that the original document is parsed, saved or serialized with the `&amp;` resolved and parsed again. Can you describe the full processing being done on your document?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't understand why you say document is parsed, serialized and parsed again. Thanks anyway

Comment: I meant, do you have an operation that 1) parses the XML, 2) saves the result of parsing (for example in a file), and 3) re uses this result for another parsing operation? I suspect that `DESIGN &amp;CONFORT` is ok for first parsing, but when you save the result, you may the obtain text such `DESIGN &CONFORT` which will throw you the error because it corresponds to a parsed entity call.

Comment: Thanks for you reactivity. I see now what you meant, I don't think so but I have to do some test in order to guarantee. I'll let you know.

Comment: Yes, in effect there was two parsing operation, the first one happened correctly but it leaved the parsed &amp ; (&) in the file so the second one didn't parse it rightly. Thank you very much